# Injecting dependent bean

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, ejb-3.0, cdi

I have a class

**EntiyFacadeImpl.java**

```
@Stateless
public class EntityFacadeImpl implements EntityFacade {

    @EJB
    ICustomerBean customerBean;

    public void printCustomer(Customer c) {
        customerBean.printCustomer(c);
        customerBean.additionalFieldsHandler(c.getAdditionalFields().toString());
    }

}
```

Where **ICustomerBean** is @Local interface and have two implementation classes **CustomerBean.java** and **CustomerBeanExt.java** where later one extends **CustomerBean.java**

```
@Stateless(name = "CustomerBean")
public class CustomerBean implements ICustomerBean {

    public void printCustomer(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println(customer);
    }

    public void additionalFieldsHandler(String additionalFields) {
        // an empty implemetation here
    }
}

@Stateless(name = "CustomerExtBean")
public class CustomerExtBean extends CustomerBean implements ICustomerBean {

    @Override
    public void additionalFieldsHandler(String additionalFields) {
            // some custom implemetation
        System.out.println("Additional Fields: "+additionalFields);
    }
}
```

**ICustomer** interface looks like this

```
@Local
public interface ICustomerBean {
    public void printCustomer(Customer c);
    public void additionalFieldsHandler(String additionalFields);
}
```

My aim is that whenever I inject my **EntityFacade** (interface for EntityFacadeImpl) in **SimpleRESTPojo.java** only, I want **CustomerExtBean** to be inject in it, while when any other class injects it I want **CustomerBean** to be injected

```
@Path("/pojo")
public class SimpleRESTPojo {

    @EJB
    private EntityFacade entityFacade;

}
```

My app's entry point is EntityFacade only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after reading your question, it looks like you're trying to introduce tight coupling.  CDI doesn't make `EntityFacade` aware of where it was injected in to.  I don't see a way to do this.

What you could do is create an extended version of `EntityFacade` that used this injection point:

```
@Inject
@Extended //or whatever qualifier you come up with
private ICustomerBean  customerBean;
```

and then use that same qualifier on the extended `EntityFacade`.